# It is possible to call without sim by adding a number as emergency number...?

Tags: calls, emergency-calls

It is possible to call anyone without sim card...I mean adding anyones number as emergency call number and call anyone as emergency call?

Answer (score 0):

You cant add a number as emergency number. The mobile phone and the SIM card have a preprogrammed list of emergency numbers. When the user tries to set up a call using an emergency number known by a GSM or 3G phone, the special emergency call setup takes place. 
You can dial emergency numbers without sim card. But the numbers should valid in that country. Here are some emergency numbers
112, 911, 118, 119, 000, 110, 08, 999 etc.
However, some GSM networks will not accept emergency calls from phones without a SIM card, or even require a SIM card that has credit. For example, Latin American networks typically do not allow emergency calls without a SIM. Also, GSM phones sold in some countries like USA do not accept 112 as an emergency number even if they have a SIM card inserted.